# CGLIB not able to intercept methods in a superclass/superinterface

Tags: java, proxy, cglib

May be I'm not thinking hard enough or the answer is really elusive. Quick scenario (Try the code out. It compiles).

Consider a legacy interface

```
public interface LegacyInterfaceNoCodeAvailable{
    void logInfo(String message);
}
```

The consider a legacy implementation of the interface above

```
public abstract class LegacyClassNoCodeAvailable implements LegacyInterfaceNoCodeAvailable{

    public abstract void executeSomething();

    public void rockItOldSchool(){
        logInfo("bustin' chops, old-school style");
    }

    @Override
    public void logInfo(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Now I come in as this ambitious person and writes a class for a 'New' system but that runs inside the 'Legacy' framework, hence I have to extend the legacy base class.

```
public class lass SpankingShiny extends LegacyClassNoCodeAvailable{

    public void executeSomething(){
        rockItOldSchool();
        logInfo("I'm the King around here now");
        System.out.println("this new stuff rocks!!");
    }
}
```

Everything works great, just like you would expect:

```
SpankingShiny shiny = new SpankingShiny();
shiny.executeSomething();
```

The above code yields (as expected):

```
bustin' chops, old-school style
I'm the King around here now
this new stuff rocks!!
```

Now as you can see, the 'System.out.println()' faithfully prints the desired output. But I wish to replace the 'System.out.println()' with a logger.

Problem:

I'm unable to have the CGLIB proxy intercept the method to 'logInfo(string)' and have it print out my desired message through a logger (I have done the logging configuration right by the way). That method invocation 'apparently' does not hit the proxy.

Code:

```
public class SpankingShinyProxy implements MethodInterceptor{

    private SpankingShiny realShiny;
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SpankingShinyProxy.class);

    public SpankingShinyProxy(SpankingShiny realShiny) {
        super();
        this.realShiny = realShiny;
    }

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Object proxyObj, Method proxyMethod, Object[] methodParams, MethodProxy methodProxy) throws Throwable {
        String methodName = proxyMethod.getName();
        if("logInfo".equals(methodName)){
            logger.info(methodParams[0]);
        }
        return proxyMethod.invoke(realShiny, methodParams);
    }

    public static SpankingShiny createProxy(SpankingShiny realObj){
        Enhancer e = new Enhancer();
        e.setSuperclass(realObj.getClass());
        e.setCallback(new SpankingShinyProxy(realObj));
        SpankingShiny proxifiedObj = (SpankingShiny) e.create();
        return proxifiedObj;
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String... args) {

        SpankingShiny shiny = new SpankingShiny();
        shiny.executeSomething();

        SpankingShiny shinyO = SpankingShinyProxy.createProxy(shiny);
        shinyO.executeSomething();
    }
```

The above code yields (NOT as expected):

```
bustin' chops, old-school style
I'm the King around here now
this new stuff rocks!!
bustin' chops, old-school style
I'm the King around here now
this new stuff rocks!!
```

Where would I be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my case, the `realObj` was a proxy itself (a Spring Bean - a `@Component`).

So what I had to do was change the `.setSuperClass()` part in:

```
Enhancer e = new Enhancer();
e.setSuperclass(realObj.getClass());
e.setCallback(new SpankingShinyProxy(realObj));
SpankingShiny proxifiedObj = (SpankingShiny) e.create();
```

I changed:

```
e.setSuperclass(realObj.getClass());
```

To:

```
e.setSuperclass(realObj.getClass().getSuperClass());
```

This worked because, as said, `realObj.getClass()` was a CGLIB proxy itself, and that method returned a crazy-name-CGLIB-generated class, such as `a.b.c.MyClass$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1e18666c`. When I added `.getSuperClass()` it returned the class it should have been returning in the first place.

Comment: Great answer! Sorted my problem just fine.
And for those that are using Spring, you can take advantage of:
```ClassUtils.getUserClass(type);```
In this case the ```.getSuperClass()``` will be used only when you're dealing with CGLIB proxies (which is pretty much the reason why you may be looking for this solution).

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you are lucky that your proxy is not hit. If you were referencing the actual proxy within `intercept`, you would end up with an endless loop since your reflective method incocation would get dispatched by the same `SpankingShinyProxy`. Again and again.

The proxy is not working since you simply delegate the method call `executeSomething` on your proxy to some unproxied object. You must not use `realObj`. All method calls must be dispatched by your proxy, also those method calls that are invoked by the  must hit the proxy itself!

Change the last line in your `intercept` method to `methodProxy.invokeSuper(proxyObj, args)`. Then, construct your object by using the `Enhancer`. If your constructor for `SpankingShiny` does not need arguments, calling `create` without any arguments if fine. Otherwise, supply the objects you would normally supply to the constructor to the `create` method. Then, only use the object that you get from `create` and you are good.

If you want more information on cglib, you might want to read this blog article: http://mydailyjava.blogspot.no/2013/11/cglib-missing-manual.html